# Dynamic Class creation - FileNotFound Exception

Tags: c#

I was experimenting with dynamic class creation at runtime but I get the following error when i run my program at the last line.  Does anyone know how to solve this?  I tried searching similar problems online but none of the solutions have helped me. Thanks in advance for any help

Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\jelsfwqz.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

```
string code2 = "using System;" +
"using System.Collections.Generic;" +
"using System.Linq;" +
"using System.Text;" +
"" +

"    public sealed class CustomClass" +
"    {" +

"    }" 
;


        // Compiler and CompilerParameters
        CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

        CompilerParameters compParameters = new CompilerParameters();

        CodeDomProvider compiler = CSharpCodeProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

        // Compile the code
        CompilerResults res = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compParameters, code2);

        // Create a new instance of the class 'CustomClass'
        object myClass = res.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("CustomClass");
```

Comment: Don't ignore CompilerResults.Errors

Comment: Thank you.  I will add that to my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed code:

```
    string code2 = 
    "    public sealed class CustomClass" +
    "    {" +

    "    }"
    ;


    // Compiler and CompilerParameters
    CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

    CompilerParameters compParameters = new CompilerParameters();

    CodeDomProvider compiler = CSharpCodeProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

    **compParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");**


    // Compile the code
    CompilerResults res = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compParameters, code2);

    // Create a new instance of the class 'CustomClass'
        object myClass = res.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("CustomClass");
```